# Exit from a loop python 3

Tags: function, python-3.x, while-loop, exit

im new ish to python and ive got this code and i want it to allow for the word "exit" to be entered at any time when inputting. And once that is done, it closes the script.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
import sys

while True:

    def inputs():   
        first=input("Enter your first name: ")
        last=input("Enter your last name: ")
        gender=input("Enter your gender: ")
        form=input("Enter your form: ")

        file = open("signup.txt", "a")
        #Records the user's details in the file
        file.write("\nFirst name: "+first+", Last name: "+last+", Gender: "+gender+", Form: "+form)
        #Closes the file
        file.close()

        if input(inputs) == "exit":
            sys.exit()

    inputs()
```

Comment: there are no loops here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just encapsulate input function to exit on the "exit" word :

```
import sys

def exitInput(prompt):
  pInput = input(prompt)
  return pInput if pInput != "exit" else sys.exit()

def inputs():
  first = exitInput("Enter your first name: ")
  last = exitInput("Enter your last name: ")
  gender = exitInput("Enter your gender: ")
  form = exitInput("Enter your form: ")
  file = open("signup.txt", "a")
  file.write("\nFirst name: "+first+", Last name: "+last+", Gender: "+gender+", Form: "+form)
  file.close()

inputs()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check every time after input that it is **exit** or not. if it is **exit** then terminate the program. as your code you can put the code given bellow after every time of taking input

```
if input(inputs) == "exit":
        sys.exit()
```